# Exception capturing and Error logging

Tags: c#, logging, exception, error-handling

I have got a utility class, called `ErrorLog`, which basically does some basic error logging kinda stuff, recording error messages, stacktraces, etc.

So in my main c# app, I almost always chuck this piece of code, `ErrorLog el = new ErrorLog()`  into the `catch(Exception e)` part, and then start calling its methods to do logging.

For example, here is 1 of the methods in `ErrorLog` class

```
public void logErrorTraceToFile(string fname, string errorMsg, string errorStackTrace)
{ 
    //code here
}
```

Anyway, I am just wondering if it's a good approach to log errors in this way? It seems to me that this solution is a bit clumsy. (considering in each catch block you create `el` object and call its method, repeatedly.)

Also, in terms of storing error log files, where it the **best / most reasonable** location to save them? Currently, I just hard-coded the directory, `C:\ErrorLogs\`, as I am still testing a few things. But I do want to get it right before I forget.

So any ideas or suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually I'm using the Singleton pattern to have one application wide Logger.

```
public class Logger
{
    protected static Logger _logger;

    protected Logger()
    {
        // init
    }

    public void Log(string message)
    {
        // log
    }

    public static Logger GetLogger()
    {
        return _logger ?? _logger = new Logger();
    }
}
```

As a place to store data I would use the application data or user data directory, only there you can be sure to have write access.

**Edit:** That's how you would use the Logger from any place in your code:

```
Logger.GetLogger().Log("test");
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at  [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/)  This is very efficient in handling and catching errors in the application.

The errors get logged in the database.

Comment: But its good to know anyway. it'd be helpful for asp.net dev in the future.